# iPhone5S as an Android Device Model on Playstore Device Listing?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play

I was uploading android app on Play-store today morning and see something weird while uploading the app.

While looking at the devices compatible with the app I found its also showing "iPhone 5S"? Isn't it something not expected?

I presume there must be some android device model with the same exact name like "iPhone 5S"? Still not aware about any kind of android device model with the same name?

[image]

Comment: the device name is simply a string in a text file called `ro.build` somewhere in the system files. Any ROM or doggy device manufacturer (or even a rooted device) can write whatever there. The PlayStore app on the devices bulk-collect device names to show in this panel.